# Sharepoint 2013,Stop uploading excel file every thursday at 10:00 pm

Tags: .net, date, sharepoint

please how i can Stop/grant uploading excel file in SHAREPOINT 2013 every thursday at 10:00 pm and and allow it from monday to wednesday?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean to restrict the upload possibilities to a sharepoint document library. One solution is to attach an event handler to this document library, where you handle the `Item_Adding` event. Inside this eventhandler you might cancel the upload based on your conditions.